# Members plugin, how to batch assign permissions to articles

Tags: plugins

I have 500 articles in my KB, I need to add content permissions to many of them, hoping to avoid the attribution article by article.
I would make it via SQL, I looked up for the `wp_members` table in phpMyAdmin but cannot find it. What is the table prefix the plugin creates for managing its data?
Also, can I put the active roles in the article list view, so to have a glance of the permissions.
Thanks!